# Clean up the outdated cache of mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, http, browser-cache, cache-control

Is there any good way to **clean up the outdated cache** of the mobile browser?

- **good compatibility**
- implement this function through front-end technology

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways for cache busting,

**Query params**- Adding version as a param to the file name -

```
<script src="main.js?v=3.0.0"></script>
```

**# Change in file name** - change file name for each versions,

```
main.version.3.0.0.sa54dasdsf.js 
main.version.4.0.0.we343325.js
```